# How can I access the address of a contract in a drizzle dapp?

Tags: truffle, dapp-development, react, drizzle

I've started working from the drizzle box and can access functions within contracts, but if I want to give an allowance to a contract address so it can use users tokens how can I give the correct address? drizzleOptions contains contracts which have addresses per network but I don't think I can figure out which network is current without a web3 instance, there must be a simple way though to get the address of a contract on the current network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to access the drizzle context object, in the react component. I assume you are working on the 'Home.js' component.

For example:

`this.drizzle = context.drizzle`

in the constructor of the component and see https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle-react/issues/22,

Once you have that working then,

`this.drizzle.contracts.TutorialToken.address` or equivalently

`context.drizzle.contracts.TutorialToken.address` should return the address of the network, however, since I am no expert in react, there may be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The address is part of the contract API that is loaded together with the drizzle option

So when you just `console.log(drizzle)` there is the solution. You can view the address directly in you Chrom-Browser when openening the dev tools -> console

Let's assume your contact name is SimpleToken, then

drizzle.contracts.SimpleToken.address hold the contract address

make sure that before you using this, drizzle.contracts.SimpleToken.address is in sync. Otherwise you will get undefined as a return value or an fat red error on you chrome console.

Hope this helps